# Laravel Image intervention giving 503 error on uploading

Tags: laravel, image

Image interversion is creating 503 error while uploading image.
It is working properly at localhost but not working on server.

```
post_max_size=15121212M 
max_execution_time=15121212
upload_max_filesize=133335M
memory_limit=1212121212M
```

php.ini code set to maximum values but all in vein

Comment: Can you also add your code where you upload image and error message you get?

Comment: `if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
             $img = Image::make($request->file('image'));
            $height = Image::make($request->file('image'))->height();
            $width = Image::make($request->file('image'))->width();
             $widthi=round($width/2)-40;
             $heighti=round($height/2)-40;
             $img->insert(public_path('logo.png'), 'bottom-right', $widthi, $heighti);
            $img->save(public_path('property/'.$imageuploaddirectory.'/banner.png'));
         }`